# Any way to get the version of xcode being used at build-time?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several legacy projects that clients occasionally ask for a minor change on.  Some of them break when built with versions of Xcode/iOS SDK greater than X.  I'd like to plop some build-time scripts in these projects so it spits out an error if you are building with the wrong version of Xcode.  Is there any environment variable or something I can look at to check this?  I have a few different versions of Xcode installed, so I can't just drill into the actual Xcode .app and check there.  Thanks.

Comment: The closest thing I could find in the docs is the [`GCC_VERSION`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shell script that gets run as a build step with this in it:

`/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version`

Comment: This is not an environment variable.

Comment: It is not. I could not find an environment variable for this. So I provided the next best thing, something that could be queried at build time.

Comment: Thanks Almo, but this just prints out whatever the most recent version of xcode I have installed (or seems to anyway).  That's why I was hoping for something like an environment variable.

Comment: Well, this tells you what version of Xcode you're using, and you could check against a user-set variable for which version you need used.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script like this for prevent other XCode version compile (only accept XCode 7.3)

```
XCODE_VERSION_TEAM="0730"

if [ ${XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL} != ${XCODE_VERSION_TEAM} ]; then
    echo -n "error: Only accept Xcode v"
    echo -n ${XCODE_VERSION_TEAM:1:1}.${XCODE_VERSION_TEAM:2:1}.${XCODE_VERSION_TEAM:3:1}
    echo " for compile. See 'Run Script Phase'."
    return -1
fi
```